# Adding text to spplot [R]

Tags: r, r-sp

I performed a spatial interpolation in R with some data and got stuck with creating the map. I have to use [spplot](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/sp/docs/spplot) for doing so. When I test the code sample from there:

```
 data(meuse)
 coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y
 l2 = list("SpatialPolygonsRescale", layout.north.arrow(), offset =
 c(181300,329800), scale = 400)
 l3 = list("SpatialPolygonsRescale", layout.scale.bar(), offset =
 c(180500,329800), scale = 500, fill=c("transparent","black"))
 l4 = list("sp.text", c(180500,329900), "0")
 l5 = list("sp.text", c(181000,329900), "500 m")

 spplot(meuse, c("ffreq"), sp.layout=list(l2,l3,l4,l5),
 col.regions= "black", pch=c(1,2,3),
 key.space=list(x=0.1,y=.95,corner=c(0,1)))
```

everything works as intended. When I apply this to my dataset, I get an error

```
Error in printFunction(x, ...) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

This is how my code looks like:

```
l2 = list("SpatialPolygonsRescale", layout.north.arrow(), offset =
            c(5400000,500000), scale = 400)
l3 = list("SpatialPolygonsRescale", layout.scale.bar(), offset =
            c(5400000,500000), scale = 25000, fill=c("transparent","black"))
l4 = list("sp.text", c(5400000,500000), "0")
l5 = list("sp.text", c(5400000,500000), "25 km")

# Use the ColorBrewer library for color ramps
library(RColorBrewer)
precip.pal <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(7, name="Blues"))

# plot the interpolation
spplot(bla.krige, zcol='bla.pred', col.regions=precip.pal,contour=TRUE, 
       col='black',
       pretty=TRUE,
       scales=list(draw = TRUE),
       labels=TRUE,
       layout=list(l2,l3,l4,l5))
```

Any idea how I can solve this problem? My data looks pretty much the same as in the example given in the spplot documentation. Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by myself...I was a bit sloppy.

1. Although calling the package `sp`, the argument is still `sp.layout`, not just `layout` (rtfm issue).
2. I mixed up latitude and longitude for my spatial extent. So it should be `c(500000,5400000)` rather than `c(5400000,500000)`.

Comment: Regarding your first problem you should know that in R the . is not a member access operator like in other programming languages (Java, C#), it is just a normal letter that can be used for naming variables and methods. I assume that is why you thought you could skip sp.